# How can I restrict re-render the child components in drawer?

Tags: reactjs

I am using drawer in React.js. When the drawer is open and I close it, it will automatically re-render the child components. I don't need to re-render the child components. How do I restrict it? I tried useMemo library in React, but it is also not working.

Comment: Which component do you use for the drawer?